# jsf post redirect get pattern good practice

Tags: jsf, post, redirect, get, design-patterns

I use JSF 2.1.7 Mojarra with Facelets, and most of my pages are crud pages, backed with view-scoped managed beans, using post to the same page (return ""). Depending on flags I have in the bean, I render the html code I want (list of results, forms for insert/edit/delete) into the crud page.

In terms of good practice, good design, good working of any webapp, etc... is it better to use PRG pattern? Are there any serious problems if PRG is not used?

In my case, I'm thinking of using PRG, but I think it's quite tedious, as f:viewparams have to be used for any form field, and it's a hard (tedious) job to change all the pages. Am I wrong? Which changes do I have to do convert POST to GET in JSF?

The reason I'm thinking of use PRG (apart for the bad user experience showing alert popups) is a problem I have posting a form when the session has already timedout.

Thank you.